# SASS (not SCSS) syntax for css3 keyframe animation

Tags: css, sass, keyframe

Is there any way to write keyframes in SASS?

Every example I have found is actually SCSS, even when it says it's SASS.  To be clear, I mean the one with no curly brackets.

Comment: By the way, what's the different between SASS and SCSS? Is not `.scss` the extension format of SASS files?

Comment: @M98 Check out the code examples [on the sass site](http://sass-lang.com/guide).  They released 2 syntaxes - Scss and Sass.  Both have the same functionality but Sass is strict about indentation, allowing it to lose the curlies brackets and semi-colons.

Comment: hint: I turn to [https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-sass] when I need to find the corresponding sass syntax of something I do know in scss.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Here is how you implement css keyframes in the Sass syntax:

```
@keyframes name-of-animation
  0%
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  100%
    transform: rotate(360deg)
```

Here is a Sass mixin to add vendor prefixes:

```
=keyframes($name)
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$name}
    @content
  @-moz-keyframes #{$name}
    @content
  @-ms-keyframes #{$name}
    @content
  @keyframes #{$name}
    @content
```

Here's how to use the mixin in Sass syntax:

```
+keyframes(name-of-animation)
  0%
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  100%
    transform: rotate(360deg)
```

Comment: can you provide for spin that transforms from 0 to 360 deg. It is very easy in css but it is getting very complicated in sass.

Comment: @daviestar regarding the Sass mixin to **add vendor prefixes**: in my opinion is also a good idea to handle vendor prefixes with some sort of **build tool** (say Gulp or Grunt, for instance). A good one could be [gulp-autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer).

Comment: true dat @vcoppolecchia

Answer (score 2):

Create keyframes like so:

```
@keyframes name
  0%
    transform: scale(1)
  50%
    transform: scale(1.5)
  100%
    transform: scale(1)
```

then use

```
.example-btn
  animation: name 2s linear infinite
```

If you store keyframes in other .sass file, you just need import this file(with keyframes) and everything will work good.